# How to open video picker view or gallery in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Currently I can open image picker using **$cordovaImagePicker**, but also I want to open video picker for picking the video from gallery/ video gallery.

How can I achieve above task/ thing?

Currently there is no any plugin for picking videos. And html input type=file is open the Mobile Gallery but it's not provide the file path. 
Is there another way for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Camera plugin  [org.apache.cordova.camera](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-example-cordova-camera/blob/master/plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/doc/index.md)
and use the following options for select a video from the gallery (Tested in Android):

```
    var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType:Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then( ...
```